# Как добавить виджет в существующее приложение xamarin forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, xaml, виджет, xamarin.forms

Как создать виджет добавляемый на рабочий стол мобильного устройства в xamarin forms отдельно для каждой операционной системы?

Можно ли, и если можно, то как написать код виджета на xaml аналогично написанию страниц?

Виджет должен быть встроен в само приложение(не отдельным приложением).

Долго искал как провернуть такое на xamarin forms, но так и не нашел информацию

Comment: Добавляй отдельно для IOS и Andriod

Comment: Вот для Android, первая же ссылка https://marcofolio.net/app-widget-xamarin-android/